# ¿Qué es exactamente "object" en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, objeto

Me surgió una duda de qué es exactamente la clase u objeto `object` en Python.

Según sé, en Python todo es creado por la metaclase `type` (pero por lo que explicaré a continuación me hace dudar):

```
>>> str.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> int.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> bool.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> float.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> A.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> ClassName = type('ClassName', (), {})
>>> ClassName.__class__
<class 'type'>
```

---

Por otra parte `object` es una instancia de `type`:

```
>>> object.__class__
<class 'type'>
>>> isinstance(object, type)
True
```

Lo que no me cuadra en absoluto es esto:

```
>>> isinstance(type, object)
True
```

¿Cómo es posible que `type` sea una instancia de `object` si se supone que `object` es una instancia de `type`? No tiene sentido. Parece que Python se esté contradiciendo...

Además de esto, `object` es una clase base de `type`:

```
>>> type.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
```

Pero según Python `object` es una instancia de `type` y según eso, ¿cómo es posible que una clase (`type`) herede de un instancia (`object`) de dicha clase?

Entonces en base a esto: ¿Qué es exactamente `type` y `object`? ¿Cuál de las dos es la metaclase o "la clase que crea clases" "verdadera" por así decirlo? Según tenia entendido era `type`:

```
type('MyClass', (), {})
```

---

Y por curiosidad de saber más sobre object, al parecer todas las clases heredan o descienden de él:

```
>>> int.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>> bool.__bases__
(<class 'int'>,)
>>> str.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>> float.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> A.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
```

¿Por qué esto es así?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tal vez un <strike>buen</strike> resumen sea:

> En Python todo es un objeto y todo lo demás no existe, además todo objeto tiene un tipo. Y si, un tipo también es un objeto...

Es común que, a la hora de dar soporte a la POO en un lenguaje, exista una metaclase de la que deriven las demás clases y una clase raíz de la que deriva todo objeto. Por ejemplo, en Smalltalk existe `Class` y `Object` respectivamente. Bien, podríamos pensar que en Python sus equivalentes son `type` y `object`, pero si como se menciona arriba, todo es un objeto, `type` también lo es y por tanto debería derivar de `object`. Como `object` es una clase, debería derivar de `type`... lo cual nos lleva a una pregunta clásica en filosofía y que es tu pregunta en esencia:

> **¿Qué fue antes el huevo o...? Perdón, ¿el objeto o el tipo?**

En Python todo gira en torno al concepto de "objeto", es la abstracción de Python para representar datos. Todo dato en Python es representado por objetos o por relaciones entre ellos.

Todo objeto tiene a su vez tres características:

- **Una identidad**: es exclusiva de cada objeto y jamás cambia mientras exista. En CPython se usa la dirección de memoria del objeto. Es lo que el operador de identidad (`is`) compara y lo que el builtin `id()` retorna.
- **Un valor**: los datos representados por el objeto, el valor puede cambiar en objetos mutables como las listas. En objetos inmutables como las cadenas no puede ser modificado después de la instancia del objeto.
- **Un tipo**: el tipo (o clase) de un objeto es la clase de la que es instancia. Una clase también es un objeto y por tanto tiene un tipo, el tipo de éstos objetos es `type`. El mismo `type` es también un objeto y su tipo es también `type`, único objeto con ésta característica.

Conceptualmente, desde Python 2.2 "tipo" y "clase" son lo mismo.

### **`object`**

La clase `object` es la base de la jerarquía de clases en Python. **Todas las clases** son subclases de la clase de `object`, por lo tanto **todos los objetos** son instancias de `object`. Dicha clase contiene el esqueleto básico de una clase, de ella provienen los métodos esenciales que toda clase tiene como `__getattribute__`, métodos que siempre podemos llamar desde una subclase para, por ejemplo en el caso de '`__getattribute__`', hacer imposible que existan atributos privados en Python por mucho que nos empeñemos...

Recordemos, que una clase en si misma es también un objeto, un objeto alojado en memoria con las instrucciones para construir otros objetos.

```
>>> import sys
>>> isinstance(sys, object)
True

>>> isinstance(str, object)
True

>>> class Foo: pass
>>> isinstance(Foo, object)
True

>>> isinstance(type(type), object)
True

>>> isinstance(object, object)  # ?????
True

>>> isistance("El Universo", object) # !!!!!
True
```

### **`type`**

Definida en C (`PyObject* PyType_Type`), es la única metaclase preconstruida que hay en CPython. Una metaclase es simplemente una clase cuyas instancias son también clases.

Lo mismo que afirmamos que todo es un objeto, **todo tiene un tipo**, si, `object` también...

```
>>> type(object)
type
```

pero a diferencia de lo que ocurría con `object`, no todo es un tipo (o deriva de `type`):

```
>>> import sys
>>> isinstance(sys, type)
False

>>> isinstance(str, type)
True

>>> class Foo: pass
>>> isinstance(Foo, type)
True

>>> isistance("El Universo", type)
False
```

Todo parece un lío, puede parecer que `type` y `object` heredan mutuamente una de otra, pero ésto no es realmente cierto, de hecho esto es intrínsecamente imposible conceptualmente en POO. Además hay que tener siempre presente que nos movemos en un nivel dónde realmente la POO no existe, se está creando. CPython se implementa en C y C no entiende de POO. Ni `object` hereda de `type` ni `type` de `object` a éste nivel, no existe la herencia simplemente.

Más que heredarse mutuamente, lo que ocurre es que `object` es instancia de `type` y `type` deriva de `object`. Efectivamente no deja de haber una relación cíclica que se resuelve a nivel de C en varios pasos y con varios indirecciones de por medio en las que no voy a entrar.

En el nivel de Python, el pequeño párrafo del inicio de la respuesta debe cumplirse siempre para respetar el modelo de datos:

- Cómo todo es un objeto, `type` tiene que ser un objeto para existir.
- Cómo `object` es el tipo base de todos los objetos, es un tipo y como tipo debe ser una instancia de `type`.

---

Si nos abstraemos de todos los detalles de implementación y conceptuales, podríamos quedarnos para no perturbar nuestra existencia con lo siguiente:

La clase base para todo objeto es `object` (que no sea la propia `object` claro), siempre, siempre, siempre:

```
>>> class Foo(): pass
>>> Foo.__bases__
(object,)

>>> object.__bases__
()

>>> type.__bases__
(object,)
```

Todo objeto tiene un tipo, que es simplemente la clase de la que es instancia, por eso tipo y clase son conceptos equivalentes. Muy bonito hasta aquí, pero si todo objeto tiene un tipo y una clase es también un objeto, ¿qué tipo le asignamos a un objeto "clase"? Aquí es dónde entra `type` precisamente, es el tipo de todo objeto "clase", incluida `object` y `type` misma.

La clase `type` expuesta a través del builtin `type()` nos permite crear nuevos tipos/clases dinámicamente, como buena metaclase nos permite crear instancias que son clases, pero ¿alguien adivina en éste punto cuál es la clase base de las clases que `type` nos genera?

```
>>> new = type("Bar", (), {})

>>> type(new)
type

>>> new.__bases__
(object,)  # No podía ser de otra forma....
```

Hay que tener siempre presente la distinción entre derivar/heredar y ser instancia de algo. Una cosa es "ser una instancia de X" y otra muy distinta "ser una clase que derivada de X":

```
class Foo():
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

foo = Foo()
```

`foo` es instancia de `Foo`, pero no hereda de ella, en cambio `Bar` si deriva de `Foo`, pero no es instancia de ella.

---

### Resumen

- Todo objeto menos el propio `object` deriva de `object`, si no, no existe.
- La metaclase `type` como un objeto que existe, deriva de `object`.
- La metaclase `type` crea otras clases que todas, sin excepción, derivan de `object`.
- Por lo tanto, `object` no deriva/hereda de nada, pero `type` si es instancia de `object`.
- Tanto `object` como `type` son clases, luego su tipo es `type`, por lo que `type` es la única clase en la que se cumple que:

  ```
  type(type) == type
  ```

Por lo tanto podemos considerar que **una clase/tipo es una instancia de `type` y deriva siempre de `object`.**

```
>>> isinstance(object, type)
True

>>> issubclass(object, type)
False

>>> isinstance(type, object)
True

>>> issubclass(type, object)
True
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Pero dices que "Ni object hereda de type ni type de object", entonces por que al hacer `type.__bases__` se ve que type hereda de object?

Comment: O es algo de C que ya no me corresponde saber mas?

Comment: Hola Julio, he retocado algo la respuesta para intentar  evitar la ambigüedad que comentas, efectivamente me refería a nivel de implementación en C, y no es que no te corresponda saber más, solo faltaría, es que no he querido meterme en ese charco, del que no se si sería capaz de salir en una sola respuesta dada mi escasa (por decir algo...) capacidad de resumen. Tampoco he mencionado nada sobre la historia que hay detrás de object, las clases de nuevo estilo y la diferencia entre tipo y clase en Python < 2.2, creo que queda lejano dado que Python 2 ha ¿muerto?. Por cierto, muy buena pregunta.

Answer (score 6):

Vaya pregunta más interesante. Te comparto mi respuesta haciendo referencia a la documentación oficial del lenguaje, pero también basándome en mi experiencia personal en el punto más profundo de tu pregunta.

---

> Y por curiosidad de saber más sobre object, al parecer todas las clases heredan o descienden de el:

Efectivamente, según la documentación del lenguaje, https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object, el objeto `object` es un objeto de tipo clase, y es una base para todas las demás clases. Por eso todas las clases, entre ellas las incorporadas en el lenguaje, como `int`, `dict`, `set`, `list`, etc., tienen como una de sus clases base al objeto `object`.

> Por otra parte object es una instancia de type:
>
> ```
> >>> object.__class__
> <class 'type'>
> >>> isinstance(object, type)
> True
> ```
>
> Lo que no me cuadra en absoluto es esto:
>
> ```
> >>> isinstance(type, object)
> True
> ```
>
> ¿Como es posible que type sea una instancia de object si se supone que object es una instancia de type? No tiene sentido. Osea python se esta contradiciendo...
>   Ademas de esto object es una clase base de type:
>
> ```
> >>> type.__bases__
> (<class 'object'>,)
> ```
>
> Pero según python object es una instancia de type y según eso ¿Como es posible que una clase (type) herede de un instancia (object) de dicha clase?

Sin duda, ésto resulta muy confuso en virtud de lo anterior. En mi experiencia no hay contradicción: siguiendo la documentación, el objeto `object` es la clase de la que derivan todas las demás; podemos explorar aún más, y encontraremos que `type` es una subclase de `object`,

```
issubclass(type, object)  # -> True
```

pero no es cierto que `object` sea subclase de `type`.  Entonces, `object` es ejemplar (instancia) de `type` por diseño, para evidenciar que `object` es una clase (o bien, un objeto de tipo clase), y todas las clases son objetos cuyo tipo es `type` (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), incluso si `object` no se obtiene de `object = type("object", bases=(), dict=some_dict)`. Análogamente pasa con `type`.

> Entonces en base a esto ¿Que es exactamente type y object? ¿Cual de las dos es la metaclase o "la clase que crea clases" "verdadera" por así decirlo?
>
> ```
> type('MyClass', (), {})
> ```

En este punto no hay mayor confusión. El objecto `object` es la base de todas las clases, y contiene los métodos comunes para todos los ejemplares de cualquier clase, incluso si estos ejemplares son clases en sí mismos. Cuando la llamas en la forma `object()`, entrega un objeto sin características ni atributos (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object), así que no crea clases. El objeto `type` es una clase, y por lo tanto su tipo es ella misma: `type`. Cuando la llamas con tres argumentos es una forma dinámica de crear una clase en lugar de declarar `class` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type. La clase que crea clases es `type` (es una metaclase), y por eso todas las clases son ejemplares de `type`.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta @Abel !!